# sqlplus error creating table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

So I am trying to create a table with multiple foreign keys however it keeps saying missing or invalid option. I have successfully created all the other tables that the keys reference without issue. What's strange is that I have found that the table creates if I remove either foreign key, but as soon as I have two foreign keys it gives me the error above. Any help is appreciated! :)

```
create table Class(
Class#  int(5),
Class_Size int(30),
Module# char(5),
Student#    char(4),
Constraint Class_PK primary key(Class#),
Constraint Class_Module_FK foreign key(Module#) references Modules(Module#) on delete cascade ),
Constraint Class_Student_FK foreign key(Student#) references Students(Student#) on delete cascade );
```

Comment: You don't have the column `Student#` in the table `Class` (for good reason), so you can't use it in the FK definition on `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra `)` at the end of second last line.

This should work

```
create table Class(
Class#  int(5),
Class_Size int(30),
Module# char(5),
Student#    char(4),
Constraint Class_PK primary key(Class#),
Constraint Class_Module_FK foreign key(Module#) references Modules(Module#) on delete cascade,
Constraint Class_Student_FK foreign key(Student#) references Students(Student#) on delete cascade );
```

Comment: Thanks so much! it was driving me mad